# What does a '*' mean as a route in app.get()?

Tags: node.js, express

I am deploying a PERN (PostgreSQL, Express, React, Node) on Heroku. I watched a tutorial on YouTube and he has some kind of this code for deploying to production:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    const path = require("path");
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./build")));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
    });
}
```

So I want to ask what does the `*` route mean in `app.get(...)` does it work same with the path `/` route or something else?

Comment: It's a wildcard. Refer to https://modernweb.com/the-basics-of-express-routes/#:~:text=Express%20allow%20you%20to%20use,req%2Cres)%20%7B%20req..

Comment: That `*` (wildcard) stands for "any route path can be here", whatever link you'll access through a GET request, will trigger that middleware.

Comment: thanks @Dekim for the blog

Answer (score 0):

Here `*` is a wild card. This means this router will handle not just /, but any request that starts with / - be it /about, /products, or even /product-details. That `*` (wildcard) stands for "any route path can be here", whatever link you'll access through a GET request, will trigger that middleware